# Is there any way to get a reference to the current frame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, menu, jframe

I have a menu bar class (MenuBarGUI) that I have put in all of my other classes and I need to know if I can close the current JFrame that it is contained in through an option in the menu. Normally I could call setVisible(false) then dispose() but because the menu bar doesn't have a reference to the current frame, I can't do that. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your MenuBarGUI class extends JMenuBar, you can use [getTopLevelAncestor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor%28%29) method to get menu bar's window.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I casted the Container and called setVisible(false) and dispose() and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`getParent()` will get the parent container.  With this method you will have to do some casting.  A more ideal option would be to have the menu bar could take an interface that includes a close method.

Here is an example:

```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
   frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
   if(bar.getParent().getParent().getParent() instanceof JFrame){
       System.out.println(bar.getParent().getParent().getParent());
   }
```

Comment: How exactly could I implement the getParent() method? I'm not sure how safe it would be to cast a container to a window (it seems very unsafe). Also, how could I implement the other method?

Comment: I added an example, but Gursel's suggestion of getTopLevelAncestor would be more appropriate if you are going this route.

Comment: Thanks. I used instanceof to check if it is a JFrame instance and then casted the Container to a JFrame and performed setVisible(false) and dispose() to close the window. It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above approaches worked for me.

Since I only need the immediate parent of a panel, accessed them directly through a super call: super.setTitle("The new Frame Title"), etc.